# Using a function to populate a new dataframe from existing CSV with specific columns and rows in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I am building a function 'rData' that has two args (an existing dataframe housed as a CSV, and the second argument is city name). I need the function to return all rows of data for a specific selection from a column (below is a snippet of the data). This will be housed in a new dataframe called UpdatedDF that can be used to run additional analysis on.

The aim of the function is to automate usage for future requests. Below is what I have so far but I am unable to implement the function to create a new dataframe. I seem to be missing some steps, appreciate your input.

[image]

```
   def rData(newCityDF, CityName):
      newCityDF = Path.loc[path['City'], "City" == (CityName), :]
```

To run the analysis for the data file, I have the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
data_path = ('file.csv') 
CityDF = pd.read_csv(data_path) 
newDF = rData(CityDF, 'London')
```

**Update based on comments:**
Thanks all for your recommendations. The errors have gone but the DF is not initializing based on the new instructions. What am i missing?

```
def rData(newCityDF, CityName):
    UpDatedDF = newCityDF.loc[newCityDF['City'] == CityName]
    return UpDatedDF

import pandas as pd
data_path = ('file.csv') 
CityDF = pd.read_csv(data_path) 
newDF = rData(CityDF, 'London')
```

Comment: I have to ask, does the ```newCityDF = Path.loc[path['City'], "City" == (CityName), :]``` actually work? I have never seen ```df.loc[]``` used in that way? Are you looking for next steps?

Comment: Looking for next steps. I was looking at ways to create the new dataframe while taking into account the requirements (using the city column and all rows that for instance include the city name London). I considered building an empty data frame and populating it but not sure how to set tha up. Open to all recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

What type of error(s) are you getting? It would be helpful to know. In your function, I see that you define a variable with the same name as the input DataFrame parameter. That would surely make the function ineffective. I also see that in the .loc function you have three different slices. You should only need the one Boolean statement for the city. So in the function,

```
UpDatedDF = newCityDF.loc[newCityDF['City'] == CityName]
```

should work. Lastly, the Pandas .loc function automatically returns a new Dataframe with the indexed rows and columns, so you don't need the UpdatedDF variable.

Comment: This worked for me, also. Your ```Path.loc``` was not right either, this makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated the code with [UpDatedDF = newCityDF.loc[newCityDF['City'] == CityName]. It's running but no amended dataframe is populating for the next stage of analysis.

Comment: You also need a return statement at the end of the function to get the new DataFrame (return UpDatedDF). Could that be the reason?

Comment: I just tried that. See the updated code in the question. Unfortunately, it is not working.

Comment: When you define data_path, I don't think you need parenthesis around the file string.

Comment: Also, make sure that the first row is being read in as the column headers.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? Can you share the edit?

Comment: When you type print(CityDF.columns), are the headers (like City, Sex, Age, etc.) in there? If so, then that is not the issue.